# Ruby - Integer to Time conversion for specific format (y m d)

Tags: ruby, time

given

```
today  = 20150307
```

and

```
t= Time.at(today).strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

why this does not return

```
   20150307
```

but instead

```
          19700822
```

I ma triyng to check if the difference of thwo date is more than 7 days but those two values are converted into integer in the first place

example

```
a = 20150227     #(25th February 2015)
x = 20150307     #(7tharch 2015)


if (x-a > 7)

puts "This Item is overdue"

else

puts "All good"

end
```

my original today is given by this

```
today =  Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d").to_i
 oneweek =  (Time.now + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)).strftime("%Y%m%d").to_i
```

if i do `oneweek - today` it will be an integer difference not a date one...

how can i achieve this???

Comment: When you use `Time.at`, `at` function expects as parameter seconds passed since the epoch (1970-01-01) and you provide a date. If you want to correctly parse your dates use Date.parse like this: `Date.parse('20150227')` and if you want the difference between those dates use `(Date.parse('20150307') - Date.parse('20150227')).to_i`

Answer (score 0):

[`Time.at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-c-at) spect the number of seconds from 1970-01-01 (Epoch).

To do what you want, try something like: `t = Date.strptime("20150307", "%Y%m%d")`